# Arithmetic operations on array of objects - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON

```
const myJSON = [
    {
        name: 'compass',
        LocX: 35,
        LocY: 312
    },
    {
        name: 'another',
        LocX: 52,
        LocY: 32
    }
]
```

From the UI, if a user wants to add number 5 to one of the two properties, how should I handle this?

I am already doing

```
myJSON.map(x => x[userSelectedProperty] + 5)
// when user selected property is 'LocX', [40, 57]
```

but I want the full array with just the value updated.

```
[
    {
        name: 'compass',
        LocX: 40,
        LocY: 312
    },
    {
        name: 'another',
        LocX: 57,
        LocY: 32
    }
]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply iterate and update the object property using [`Array#forEcah`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method which is enough for this purpose.

```js
const myJSON = [{
    name: 'compass',
    LocX: 35,
    LocY: 312
  },
  {
    name: 'another',
    LocX: 52,
    LocY: 32
  }
];

let userSelectedProperty = 'LocX';
myJSON.forEach(x => x[userSelectedProperty] += 5);

console.log(myJSON);
```

---

In case you want to create a new array then use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```js
const myJSON = [{
    name: 'compass',
    LocX: 35,
    LocY: 312
  },
  {
    name: 'another',
    LocX: 52,
    LocY: 32
  }
];

let userSelectedProperty = 'LocX';
let res = myJSON.map(x => {
  // copy properties to a new object
  let y = Object.assign({}, x);
  y[userSelectedProperty] += 5;
  return y;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a `.forEach` loop on the array to update the property within it, rather than creating a new array.

```js
const myJSON = [
    {
        name: 'compass',
        LocX: 35,
        LocY: 312
    },
    {
        name: 'another',
        LocX: 52,
        LocY: 32
    }
];
var userSelectedProperty = "LocX";
// Update the array.
myJSON.forEach(t => t[userSelectedProperty] += 5);

console.log(myJSON);
```

Comment: this mutates myJSON - not saying that's wrong in any way, it's unclear from the question

Comment: @JaromandaX Yup, I noticed the `const` there, and I was going to do something like you did in your answer. But since they didn't specify in question about this, using a forEach seems a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

No need of `map`.Use forEach and update the key value

```js
const myJSON = [{
    name: 'compass',
    LocX: 35,
    LocY: 312
  },
  {
    name: 'another',
    LocX: 52,
    LocY: 32
  }
]

function addNum(key, val) {
  myJSON.forEach(function(item) {
    item[key] = item[key] + val;

  })
}
addNum('LocX', 5)
console.log(myJSON)
```

Comment: this mutates myJSON - not saying that's wrong in any way, it's unclear from the question

Answer (score 1):

Using Object.assign makes this simply

```js
const myJSON = [
    {
        name: 'compass',
        LocX: 35,
        LocY: 312
    },
    {
        name: 'another',
        LocX: 52,
        LocY: 32
    }
]
let userSelectedProperty = 'LocX';
let newObject = myJSON.map(x => Object.assign({}, x, {[userSelectedProperty]: x[userSelectedProperty] + 5}));
console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
const myJSON = [
    {
        name: 'compass',
        LocX: 35,
        LocY: 312
    },
    {
        name: 'another',
        LocX: 52,
        LocY: 32
    }
]
var userInput = 5;
var final = myJSON.map((x, i)=>{
 return  {name:x.name ,LocX:x.LocX+userInput, LocY:x.LocY};
});
console.log(final);
```